# Unknown column $cat_name in field list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got the error: unknown column in field list, while I know for sure I haven't made any typos and the columns exist.

Anyone know what I'm overlooking?

```
<?php  
//create_cat.php  
include '../includes/connection.php';  


$cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_name']);
$cat_description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_description']);


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')  
{  
    //the form hasn't been posted yet, display it  
    echo "<form method='post' action=''>  
        Category name: <input type='text' name='cat_name' id='cat_name'/>  
        Category description: <textarea name='cat_description' id='cat_description' /></textarea>  
        <input type='submit' value='Add category' />  
     </form>"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    //the form has been posted, so save it 
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO categories(cat_name, cat_description) VALUES ($cat_name, $cat_description)';  
    $result = mysql_query($sql);  
    if(!$result)  
    {  
        //something went wrong, display the error  
        echo 'Error' . mysql_error();  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        echo 'New category successfully added.';  
    }  
}  
?>
```

Comment: Please try to use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql. Mysql is deprecated currently and removed in php >= 5.5.0. Try to use Prepared Statements to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: I know, this is from a tutorial, I first want to get it to work, and then I change it to MYSQLI

Comment: A distinct lack of these ( ' ) !!!!

Comment: Where are u getting the POST data before using to query, u need to have $cat_name = $_POST["cat_name"] and then use them in '$cal_name' inside the query

Comment: Ah i see you have $cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_name']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_name, cat_description) VALUES ('$cat_name', '$cat_description')";
```

Update:
You used ' to start a string. When doing this its not possible to use variables in the text, they will just be leaved as plain text. But when using " the variables will be evaluated.

Comment: Also add some content.

Comment: Explain why. Otherwise the same question will be asked again next time.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why people downvoted you before because it worked :) Even your unedited answer, I only needed to change the single quotes to double quotes (how does that make sense)?

Comment: Twan, single quotes will output the literal value, double quotes will output the actual value the variable is storing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your SQL query. You used single quotation marks, which is for a literal string. Your variables will not be parsed in. You need to use double quotation marks. Not only that, but for strings, you need to put single quotation marks around them when putting them into queries.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_name, cat_description) VALUES ('$cat_name', '$cat_description')";
```

You should also try not to use **mysql_*** anymore. It's been depreciated (meaning it will be removed from PHP soon). Try looking at [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) (very similar to MySQL) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Try not to be so vague, explaining the problem is the most important part. Upvoted due to edit!

Comment: @Ryan It takes time to explain, gimme time to edit my answer.